# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, include, undefined, typeerror

I am trying to filter some values by the variable, lastO, which I know has a value being properly assigned to it. However, when trying to get sortedDatesA, I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.
Here is my React code:

```
const ANDEo = [...new Set(channelSelectedData.map(data =>data.outage))].sort(sortAlphaNum) 
const lastO = ANDEo[ANDEo.length-1]
console.log(lastO)
const sortedDatesA = this.props.channelSelectedData.map(data => data.outage.includes(lastO)).slice().sort((a, b) => b.scanned - a.scanned)
```

Comment: Check if you have some data.outage equal null or undefined

Comment: Can't say anything till you send the data you are receiving in props channelSelectedData

Comment: Your data.outage is undefined or null. Try to do next: this.props.channelSelectedData?.map(data => data?.outage?.includes(lastO))?.slice()?.sort((a, b) => b?.scanned - a?.scanned)